# mod_rewrite: don't rewrite any subdomains

Tags: mod-rewrite, singlepage

Is there a way to exempt any requests to a subdomain in mod_rewrite? Right now, I have a one-page app that's redirecting everything to index.html.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Options +FollowSymlinks
  RewriteEngine On

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index
  RewriteRule (.*) index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

But I want to make sure that calls to subdomain.mydomain.com are permanently exempt from being rewritten.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a condition on the subdomain and the `-` substitution to stop the rewriting. From http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule

> There is a special substitution string named '-' which means: NO
>   substitution! This is useful in providing rewriting rules which only
>   match URLs but do not substitute anything for them.

Try

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain\.mydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index
RewriteRule (.*) index.html [L]
```